# How can I make a list of multiple attributes from different tables? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a list of multiple attributes pulled from different tables to represent a receipt.

I have manage to generate a list from 2 tables. **Description** is the Name of the item.

```
SELECT Description,Price, COUNT(O_BagelID) AS 'Items Sold'
    FROM
    Food LEFT JOIN
   `Order` ON O_FoodID = FoodlID
GROUP BY Description,Price
```

I have managed to obtain the desired output, where I get a table that shows Description,Price and Items Sold. I just want to know how to repeat this for 2 other tables without having to create 2 other queries.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x ON...LEFT JOIN z ON ...LEFT JOIN t ON..`

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please add required information like talbe layout and content. Also try to explain better what you actually mean by " a list of multiple items". There is an `edit` button below your question above. _Use it_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for UNION:

```
SELECT Description,Price, COUNT(O_BagelID) AS 'Items Sold'
FROM Food 
LEFT JOIN `Order`
 ON O_FoodID = FoodlID
GROUP BY Description,Price
UNION ALL
SELECT Description,Price, COUNT(O_BagelID) AS 'Items Sold'
FROM Another_table
LEFT JOIN `Another_table2`
 ON O_FoodID = FoodlID
GROUP BY Description,Price
```

Two thing on this query:

1) Note that I used union all -> this can produce duplicate records and if you don't want it change it to UNION

2) I didn't know the other tables column names and relations, so adjust it to your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for.